# Adding time with intervals in ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time, combobox

So I am trying desperately to add 30 minute time intervals in `combobox` when the dropdown menu appears like this:

8:00
8:30
9:00
and so forth. I write this piece of code:

```
public FormNewAppointment()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cmbBoxLength.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 30, 60, 90 });
    for (DateTime tm = time.AddHours(8); tm < time.AddHours(22); tm = time.AddMinutes(30))
    {
        cmbBoxStart.Items.Add(tm.ToShortTimeString());
    }
}
```

and I try to run the program... it crashes so I try to debug it... I put a breakpoint in the loop since the problem was focusing right there.. And to my surprise, the loop was continuing infinitely... The first value was correctly 8.00 a.m. but after that no matter how many times I ran it, only the 12.30p.m. value was inserted... I have an image below to show what I am talking about...

[image: ComboBox loop error with time intervals]

And of course the typical question arises... WHAT am I doing wrong? The syntax looks ok to me but I am missing something.. I am stuck!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your code as :

```
 for (DateTime tm = time.AddHours(8); tm < time.AddHours(22); tm = tm.AddMinutes(30))
            {
                cmbBoxStart.Items.Add(tm.ToShortTimeString());

            }
```

just `tm.AddMinutes(30))` instead of `tm = time.AddMinutes(30)`

Answer (score 2):

Each loop you are using the original `time` variable. This is not changing so will always be the same.

```
public FormNewAppointment()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cmbBoxLength.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 30, 60, 90 });

    DateTime EndTime = time.AddHours(22);    

    for (time = time.AddHours(8); time < EndTime; time = time.AddMinutes(30))
    {
        cmbBoxStart.Items.Add(time.ToShortTimeString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked too!! Simple mistake, easy to miss and if dizzy difficult to find!! Thank you!!